# Does Google app engine support redis publish and subscribe

Tags: google-app-engine, redis

Will redis publish and subscribe work on Google app engine (flexible environment).

I am using node.js

Reason for this question, I understand websockets/realtime is not supported on GAE.

Comment: can anybody help answer why downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect your redis instance to your Google App Engine Flex application instance, you just need to be aware that both of them need to be on the same region and the same network be have authorized access. You can follow the documentation's [step by step tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex) to achieve this.

I will describe in here the general steps:

**1.-** Create a Redis instance. Take note of the zone, IP address, and port of the Redis instance.

**2.-** Create an HTTP server application that establishes a connection to a Redis instance from a App Engine flexible environment instance in the same region as the Redis instance. Your "app.yaml" would look something like this:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

# update with Redis instance host IP, port
env_variables:
  REDISHOST:  redis-ip
  REDISPORT: 6379

# update with Redis instance network name
network:
  name: default
```

**3.-** Deploy your application using `gcloud app deploy`.

---

I have tried the Pub/sub behavior of redis on GAE Flex with Nodejs and has worked for me the following thing:

**on the server side**:

```
'use strict';

const redis = require('redis');
const http = require('http');
const nconf = require('nconf');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Read in keys and secrets. Using nconf use can set secrets via
// environment variables, command-line arguments, or a keys.json file.
nconf.argv().env().file('keys.json');

// Connect to a redis server provisioned over at
// Redis Labs. See the README for more info.
const pub = redis.createClient(
  nconf.get('redisPort') || '6379',
  nconf.get('redisHost') || '127.0.0.1',
  {
    'auth_pass': nconf.get('redisKey'),
    'return_buffers': true
  }
).on('error', (err) => console.error('ERR:REDIS:', err));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {

 // subscribe to the publisher

// publisher publish a message and exit
  pub.publish('notification', '{\'message\': '+req.query.message +'}', function(){

  res.send('message sent:'+ req.query.message);

  });

});

const server = app.listen(8080, () => {
  const host = server.address().address;
  const port = server.address().port;

  console.log(`Example app listening at http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

The **key.json** is something like this (i used redislab to create the redis intance):

```
{
      "redisHost": "redis-23123.c124.us-central1-1.gce.cloud.redislabs.com",
      "redisPort": 99999,
      "redisKey": "random-bunch-of-letters-for-password"
}
```

**On the client side**:

```
'use strict';

const redis = require('redis');
const nconf = require('nconf');

nconf.argv().env().file('keys.json');


const sub = redis.createClient(
  nconf.get('redisPort') || '6379',
  nconf.get('redisHost') || '127.0.0.1',
  {
    'auth_pass': nconf.get('redisKey'),
    'return_buffers': true
  }
).on('error', (err) => console.error('ERR:REDIS:', err));


sub.on('message', function (channel, message) {
 console.log('Message: ' + message + ' on channel: ' + channel + ' is arrive!');
});
sub.subscribe('notification');
```

**Notes:**

1. To try it out you have to send the messages through the GET params on the url (a param named "message").
2. Remember that GAE typically distributes requests evenly among available instances, so not all the requests from the same user would go to the same instance, however, since the client will connect directly to the redis client it won't matter as long as is stays up and listening the incoming messages (it will depend on how you implement the logic of your application though).
3. If you need to establish a persisten connection between your server and your client, trying using the supported [Websockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity). In case you use something like "socket.io" that falls back to **http long polling** there's a **Beta** feature called **Session affinity** that allows you to send requests by the same user to the same instance.

To activate Session affinity use this on your app.yaml (cookies must be enabled on all clients):

```
network:
  session_affinity: true
```

Have in mind that the documentation warns:

> App Engine applications must always be tolerant of session affinity
>   interruptions, particularly because all App Engine instances are
>   periodically restarted. Enabling session affinity can also limit the
>   effectiveness of App Engine's load balancing algorithms and can cause
>   your instance to become overloaded.

You can also use Google's **Cloud Pub/Sub** and control everything from within your app using the Google Cloud Client Library, here's an [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages) of how to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you. I understand redis can be used with GAE - however my doubt was whether redis publish/subscribe will work with GAE ? Could you please confirm it. Reason being - for redis pub/sub work I guess sockets might be required which GAE doesn't support hence my question.

Comment: I have tried using redis pub/sub on GAE Flex and has worked for me, I will edit my answer to provide more details about it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and helpful answer. Really appreciate it. Could you please upvote the question (in negative) - it would be helpful for others to follow.